# Bold matching words in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a situation where I would like to quickly bold every words in a html string (editorData) in AngularJS if word matches keywords (data or dataArray).

Keeping in mind, I can't change the case in editorData. This is the solution I came up with, but it does not help.

```
var editorData = "<p>Hello Mr. Abhimanyu, how are you?</p> <p>Congratulations on buying a new car.</p>";
var data = "Abhimanyu, you, car";
var dataArray = data.split(',');

angular.forEach(dataArray, function (d) {
    var word = d.trim().toLowerCase();
    editorData = editorData.replace(word, "<b>" + word + "</b>");
});
```

Any help is appreciated. If possible, help me debugging on Plunker.

Comment: Have you tried "bold()" method of javascript?

Comment: @AngularHarsh no, any input?

Comment: It does basically the same thing as you are doing except the boiler plate code.

Comment: @AngularHarsh but i still need looping stuff in Angular, new in ng.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here it is, whole text will be in bold:

```
var txt = "Hello Mr. Abhimanyu, how are you?";
 txt = txt.bold();
 document.write("bold text " + txt);
```

Comment: Many thanks, but this will not help in said situation.

Comment: Ok. So you want to match words and then make some selected words bold?